# How avoid code replication in the following example? C++ / Cuda

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, refactoring, replication

EDIT: This code is working, but it looks there are many code replication parts and i cant find a way arround this.

In the MatrixDevice class i want to call the kernel functions in kerne.cu. 
I reduce the MatrixDevice class to only showing this concept how i do it actually.

From MatricDevice i have some functionens to add MatrixDevice with other MatrixDevice or number, this should work for different types, in this example with float and double, this should be no problem with templates, but i have to declare the overloading functions MatrixCudaOperations extern because i cannot include a .cu file into a .h/.cpp file.

matrixdevice.h

```
extern void MatrixCudaOperations(const float* a, const float* b, float* result, size_t rows, size_t cols, EOperation operation);
extern void MatrixCudaOperations(const float* a, float b, float* result, size_t rows, size_t cols, EOperation operation);
extern void MatrixCudaOperations(const double* a, const double* b, double* result, size_t rows, size_t cols, EOperation operation);
extern void MatrixCudaOperations(const double* a, double b, double* result, size_t rows, size_t cols, EOperation operation);


template<class T>
class MatrixDevice{

    T* data;
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;

    MatrixDevice& Add(const MatrixDevice &other);
    MatrixDevice& Add(T &other);
};

//Operations with MatrixDevice
//Add MatrixDevice to this
template<class T>
MatrixDevice& MatrixDevice::Add(const MatrixDevice &other){
    MatrixCudaOperations(data, other.data, data, rows, cols, EOperation::ADD);
    return *this;
} 

//Add two MatrixDevice and return the result as new MatrixDevice
template<class T>
MatrixDevice Add(const MatrixDevice &a, const MatrixDevice &b){
    MatrixDevice result(a);
    result.Add(b);
    return result;
}

//Add two MatrixDevice to result MatrixDevice
template<class T>
void Add(const MatrixDevice &a, const MatrixDevice &b, MatrixDevice &result){
    MatrixCudaOperations(a.data, b.data, result.data, a.rows, a.cols, EOperation::ADD);
}


//Operations with Number

//Add T number to this
template<class T>
MatrixDevice& MatrixDevice::Add(T &other){
    MatrixCudaOperations(data, other, data, rows, cols, EOperation::ADD);
    return *this;
} 

//Add T number to MatrixDevice and return the result as new MatrixDevice
template<class T>
MatrixDevice Add(const MatrixDevice &a, T &b){
    MatrixDevice result(a);
    result.Add(b);
    return result;
}

//Add T number with MatrixDevice to result MatrixDevice
template<class T>
void Add(const MatrixDevice &a, T &b, MatrixDevice &result){
    MatrixCudaOperations(a.data, b, result.data, a.rows, a.cols, EOperation::ADD);
}
```

In the kernel i declare the overloading functions for MatrixCudaOpertions and the code in any function is the same.
I trying this out with templates, but it didnt work if i need a extern declaretion in MatrixDevice class.

kernel.cu

```
template<class T> __global__
void d_Add(const T* a, const T* b, T* result){
    //code
}

template<class T> __global__
void d_Add(const T* a, T b, T* result){
    //code
}

void MatrixCudaOperations(const float* a, const float* b, float* result, size_t rows, size_t cols, EOperation operation){
    dim3 blocksize(rows, cols);

    switch(operation){
        case ADD:
            d_Add<<<1,blocksize>>>(a, b, result);
            break;
        //other cases, subtract, multiply...
    }
}

void MatrixCudaOperations(const float* a, float b, float* result, size_t rows, size_t cols, EOperation operation){
    dim3 blocksize(rows, cols);

    switch(operation){
        case ADD:
            d_Add<<<1,blocksize>>>(a, b, result);
            break;
        //other cases, subtract, multiply...
    }
}

void MatrixCudaOperations(const double* a, const double* b, double* result, size_t rows, size_t cols, EOperation operation){
    dim3 blocksize(rows, cols);

    switch(operation){
        case ADD:
            d_Add<<<1,blocksize>>>(a, b, result);
            break;
        //other cases, subtract, multiply...
    }
}

void MatrixCudaOperations(const double* a, double b, double* result, size_t rows, size_t cols, EOperation operation){
    dim3 blocksize(rows, cols);

    switch(operation){
        case ADD:
            d_Add<<<1,blocksize>>>(a, b, result);
            break;
        //other cases, subtract, multiply...
    }
}
```

Comment: why does it not work? If you have compile errors please include them in the question

Comment: this code is working, but there is in my opinion many code replication, and this is only for adding values.
And i cant find a way around this code replication

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the top.

```
template<class T>
class MatrixDevice;

template<class T>
static T const& to_matrix_data( T const& t ) { return t; }
template<class T>
static T const* to_matrix_data( MatrixDevice<T> const& m ) { return m.data; }

template<class T, class Rhs>
void AddInto(MatrixDevice<T>& target, MatrixDevice<T> const& src, Rhs const& rhs) {
  MatrixCudaOperations(src.data, to_matrix_data<T>(rhs), target.data, EOperation::ADD );
}

template<class T>
class MatrixDevice{
  T* data;
  size_t rows;
  size_t cols;

  template<class Rhs>
  MatrixDevice& +=(const Rhs &other)& {
    AddInto( *this, *this, other );
    return *this;
  }

  template<class Rhs>
  friend MatrixDevice operator+(MatrixDevice lhs, Rhs const& rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
};
```

Using the word `Add` for 3 distinct operations is bad.  One is increment by, the other is add, the last is add into.

So I wrote a free template function `AddInto`.  Then based increment and add on it.

My add costs at most an additional move over yours, and based off the internal structure of your matrix, a move is free.

Comment: Thanks! this helps me a lot!